# Design issue: calling services from individual operation or Manager when it is required by more than one operation

Tags: multithreading, caching

I have a list of operations to perform A,B,C (this list can grow) which performs totally different operation. Each of this operations is performed by separate java class. There is a Manager MngrY who sits in top and call A,B,C

The class which performs the operations (A,B,C) needs to call different services X1,X2,X3,X4,X5 for the purpose . We have wrapper class WX1,WX2,WX3,WX4,WX5 for calling the services. Some of the call we make from A,B,C  are common(say WX3,WX4). (may be to two of A,B,C or to three of them).

Now where should we call X1,X2,X3,X4,X5 from. Ideally each of A,B,C should call the required services. But for the ones which is shared accross all of A,B,C does it makes sense to call from MngrY and send the output of service call to each of A,B,C (it makes sense efficiency wise but design wise as MngrY should not be aware of how A,B,C operate).

So the options are

1. Call the common service call(WX3,WX4) from the MngrY and which are required individually from individual component. Is it good design?
2. Make all the service call from  Manager MngrY. Will it scale up? We might have to make lot of service request in future and we are blocking each module for the sake of others and also design wise making the MnagrY aware of requirement of each modules.
3. Make all the service call from individual component(as required) as required and make the wrapper handle duplicate request by caching. Is it good to rely on caching that two call is not made? The service have to return result within some milliseconds and cannot afford to make two calls always.
4. Or we should have a caching mechanishm in WX1,WX2,WX3,... to ensure same call does not goes twice.

Also in future we might want to call A,B,C in parallel from MngrY so in that case can will caching create a problem. As same request may go more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

In those cases where a complex, and varying sequence of operations must be performed, I usually resort to a state-machine with some sort of 'request/command/result' class, call it, say, 'OpClass'.  The manager loads up an instance of the class with everything needed to define an A, B or C operation, data, command-enumeration, links, other class instances, the lot.  In this way the OpClass instance has all the state and other information required to perform the necessary X1..X5 operations in the correct order, (if the order matters), and to ensure that an operation is not needlessly repeated - the A, B or C is encapsulated.  The OpClass is then issued to A, B or C and these agents may call X1..X5 as necessary to complete the requested operation. The OpClass should contain members for storing of any results and error-reporting, eg. a string for error messages and/or an exception object, so enabling the operation to return 'early' if something screws up and with all the information needed to, say, log the error or try again later.

TBH, I would probably aggregate A, B C into the OpClass as well, so forming a kind of 'super' OpClass that needs only loading up with data and commands and then providing with execution, eg. by a  run() method.  Moving later to parallel operations with queues, threads and/or thread-pools then becomes much simpler, actually bordering on trivial :)

Is this relevant or make sense?